# Java 7 generics type inference: return value vs method argument

Tags: java, generics, type-inference

Why the compiler is able to correctly infer the `String` type parameter in the case of a function return type.

```
public class Generics {
    private static List<String> function() {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

but it fail when the type to infer is a method parameter :

```
public class Generics {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        method(new ArrayList<>());
    }    

    private static void method(List<String> list) {

    }
}
```

The error in this case is :

```
The method method(List<String>) in the type Generics is not applicable 
for the arguments (ArrayList<Object>)
```

Comment: Because they didn't bother implementing generic type inference wherever it would be possible. I've not tested this specific case, but Java 8 brings a lot of improvements regarding type inference, in order to help with lambdas.

Comment: It is because perfect type inference is too hard problem to solve in finite time (it is on the same order of complexity as the halting problem). As such, the Java developers had to draw the line somewhere. As others have noted, they are constantly pushing the line further, but some limits have to exist.

Comment: @KonstantinNaryshkin: the work done on Java 8 shows that they drew the line to early. More useful rules *are* possible and *are being integrated* in Java 8. It's easy to say that they should have pushed it further the first time, but it's hard to predict which additional work has actual benefits. All in all the initial implementation was pretty useful. But it could have been improved earlier.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is one of the places where type inference does not yet work as expected.

Unfortunately that behaviour is perfectly valid and conforming.

The good news is that [Java 8](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/) will include [improved type inference (JEP 101)](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/101), so situations like this should compile just as you'd expect it:

> It seems reasonable that the compiler should be able to infer the type when the result of such a generic method invocation is passed to another method [...].
>
> Unfortunately, this is not allowed in JDK 5/6/7 – the only option available to the programmer is to use an explicit type-argument.

Apart from the direct improvements (i.e. situations like the ones you mention here), this change is also necessary for being able to use [Lambdas (JEP 126)](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/126) more efficiently (i.e. without having to type a lot of type information).

Comment: Yup, they have basically the exact same example written out there.

Comment: It seems that java 8 will be the greater java release since java 5. I am quite impatient to develop with it. These who still have to use java 1.4 are in my thoughts.

Answer (score 6):

The section on [inferring unresolved type arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.8) in JLS is rather complex, but I understand that the diamond of the first case occurs in a place where it is subject to an *assignment conversion*, while in the second case it occurs in a *method invocation conversion*, which follows different rules.